# Create new Object and call methods using reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I need to create an object form a class that takes parameters. Then i need reflection once again to invoke a method. Again with parameters. How is this done in PHP?

```
class X {
    public function __construct(Y y) { ... }
    public function aMethod(Z z) { ...}
}
```

I would need to do something like this:

```
$instance = ...(new "X", new Y()); // as in 'class', 'args array'
$instance->invokeMethod("aMethod", new Z());
```

I looked at the manuals but could not find a solution that works yet.

Comment: Did not downvote you, but please explain your problem in more detail. Why do you need to use reflection?

Comment: I need reflection because i write a webframework router that takes the  classes it has to invoke from a textfile. The controller classes themselves have a bunch of constructor args. Then i need to call a method, also taken from the config file and invoke it. Besides I think it is a pretty canonical question. Not with too much blur...

Comment: Reflection in slow, i would refactor - use a factory pattern to handle dependency injection

Comment: Yes. But for that I need to compile the config file into classes first. todo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$class = 'MyClass';

$obj = new $class(..);

$method = 'stuff';

$obj->$method(...);
```

This will construct an instance of MyClass and call method(..) on it. Simple.